# Is any free app in app store (mac) for editing .doc files?

Tags: macos, mac, documents

i am using mac machine in my office.

i want to know whether **any app is available in mac for editing and creating documents** (.doc files)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the obvious one is [Apache OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/porting/mac/). I don't know if it's on the app store but it's the go-to application that's free.

Comment: OpenOffice is zombie/moribund. LibreOffice is the fork that's actually still being worked on (unless someone else in the brain trust here knows of another.) Not in the app store as far as I know.

Comment: The poster linked to Apache OpenOffice, which is indeed still actively being developed (just released version 4.0.1 a few weeks ago). No open source apps are allowed in the Mac App Store, so both Apache OpenOffice and LibreOffice would have to be downloaded from the website.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, I use http://www.neooffice.org/

I also sometime use http://drive.google.com to create or open Word docs.

Answer (score 0):

Since today [Pages](http://www.apple.com/mac/pages/) is free. Pages is Apple's Word.
Actually the whole iWorks suite (Apple Microsoft office archenemy) is now free.

You can also use the iCloud version of this apps if you own an iOS device or if you have an iCloud account. https://www.icloud.com/

Comment: Pages is not free in India